# quickCheck propositional logic generator

Tags: haskell, generator, quickcheck

So I have this quickCheck propositional logic generator:

```
instance Arbitrary Form where
   arbitrary = genForm

genForm = sized genForm'
genForm' 0 = fmap Prop (choose (1,15))
genForm' n | n > 15 = genForm' (n `div` 2)
genForm' n | n > 0 =
          oneof [fmap Prop (choose (1,15)),
                 fmap Neg subform,
                 fmap Cnj subforms,
                 fmap Dsj subforms,
                 liftM2 Impl subform subform,
                 liftM2 Equiv subform subform]
          where subform = genForm' (n `div` 2)
                subforms = resize (n `div` 2) (vector (n `div` 2))
```

The datatype is defined as follows:

```
type Name = Int

data Form = Prop Name
          | Neg  Form
          | Cnj [Form]
          | Dsj [Form]
          | Impl Form Form
          | Equiv Form Form
          deriving (Eq,Ord)
```

The problem is this generator will generate in the form of: `+[]` (a disjunction of nothing). I don't want my operators to have no nested `Prop` member as it makes invalid propositional formulas. I want to make sure that there is no option to not have a `Prop` member at the end.

My thought is that this problem comes from the `resize (div n 2)`. When `n` is even this will eventually hit `0` and not go further on generating and thus create a empty member. Removing the `resize` won't help because it then won't generate a ending 'tree'. So it seems to be needed but should be tweaked in some way.

But I'm not great at Haskell and I'm having difficulty debugging/reading the documentation.

Comment: What makes those invalid? An empty disjunction is false/bottom, while an empty conjunction is true/top. Indeed, those are the only ways to express those important propositions with your type!

Comment: @dfeuer I'm quite unfamiliar with those formulations of ⊤ and ⊥. It definitely sounds correct that they are missing in `Form`.

Comment: I guess you could also express true as ``Prop 0 `Equiv` Prop 0`` and false as ``Prop 0 `Equiv` Neg (Prop 0)``, but those are neither as compact nor (IMO) as clear as `Cnj []` and `Dsj []`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply `vector` to a non-zero argument:

```
subforms = resize (n `div` 2) (vector (1 + (n `div` 2)))
```

Or use [`listOf1 arbitrary`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.14.1/docs/Test-QuickCheck.html#v:listOf1) instead of `vector`

```
subforms = resize (n `div` 2) (listOf1 arbitrary)
```

---

From a follow-up comment:

> even need the generated amount to be at least >2

Apply `vector` to a length >= 2:

```
subforms = resize (n `div` 2) (vector (2 + (n `div` 2)))
```

Or append two elements in front explicitly (using `listOf` to allow the length to also vary):

```
subforms = resize (n `div` 2) (listOf2 arbitrary)
  where
    listOf2 :: Gen a -> Gen [a]
    listOf2 gen = liftA2 (:) gen (liftA2 (:) gen (listOf gen))
    -- 1. (listOf gen) to generate a list
    -- 2. Call gen twice to generate two more elements
    -- 3. Append everything together with `(:)`
```

Comment: That's a great one, it's is at least better. Bit of an annoying mistake of mine that (just now realized that) I even need the generated amount to be at least `>2` because an conjunction of one element is still invalid.

Comment: Ok, let me adapt my answer to handle that case too.

Comment: I agree with dfeuer though that these constraints seem quite artificial.

Comment: It must be my general lack of understanding of the domain. I'm working with a provided function. quickCheck on that function results in a non exhaustive pattern. Which in fairness is true and this data might have been correctly generated. But this function under test was provided to me so I'm "assuming" they did it correctly. I'm inquiring with them about the usefulness of empty Cnj and Dsj and possible faults in their code. But I now at least have what I asked for and the trueness of what I got will be further looked at. But thanks for your quick answer.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with dfeuer that empty disjunctions and conjunctions make sense, and logically mean false and true, respectively. But if you prefer not to have such terms, then I think you are looking at the problem wrong by trying to fix it in quickcheck. Instead, fix it in your data type, by using [`NonEmpty Form`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/semigroups-0.5.0.2/docs/Data-List-NonEmpty.html) instead of `[Form]` for those constructors. Then, not only will quickcheck be unable to generate these invalid forms, but so will everyone else be unable.